# ModleNotFoundError: No module named ‘cftime._cftime’

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I installed cftime 1.5.0 from anaconda archive, but error occurs when importing the cftime.

I already checked that is installed via ‘conda list’.

Can i know what the problem is?

I’m using python 3.7 via anaconda in Redhat 6.9.

```
import cftime
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
from ._cftime import (datetime,real_datetime,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘cftime._cftime’
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Anaconda you need to activate an environment before you can actually use it. This is what is happening when you open the Anaconda prompt. Alternatively you can open any shell and run

```
conda activate
```

Only afterwards you should run

```
python
```

and import your packages. The misconception about activation comes from the fact that people keep adding the Python path to their environment. But this only allows to run Python and it's standard packages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my anaconda is already activated so it’s probably a different issue.